# How do I create a forward reference to a user-defined counter?

Tags: counters

I have created a counter to count enclosures:

```
\newcounter{enclosure}{0}
```

At the bottom of each enclosure I put:

```
\addtocounter{enclosure}{1}\vfill\hfill\Enclosure \arabic{enclosure}\clearpage
```

And that works perfectly.

However, at the page before the enclosures I need to put this at the bottom (if there are three enclosures):

```
ENCLOSURES (3)
```

I would like to make the value in the parenthesis reflect the last value of the `enclosure` counter. I've tried `\ref` and `\label` but that grabs the section counter, not these counters.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\begin{document}
\newcounter{enclosure}
\noindent
Total Enclosures: \\
\stepcounter{enclosure} Enclosure \arabic{enclosure}\\
\stepcounter{enclosure} Enclosure \arabic{enclosure}\\
\stepcounter{enclosure} Enclosure \arabic{enclosure}\\
\stepcounter{enclosure} Enclosure \arabic{enclosure}\\
Total Enclosures: \arabic{enclosure}
\end{document}
```

I want the Total Enclosures to be the same at the top as the bottom.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You'll need to write the information to the `.aux` file, and then read it. Once implemented, it'll need two runs to get it right. You can see examples of this in a few different packages, for example the `lastpage` package

Comment: Right, but is there an easy way to do it? I'd rather just use `\ref` and `\label`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\addtocounter{enclosure}{1}
```

or

```
\stepcounter{enclosure}
```

which is the same thing, just increment the counter, not make it available to `\ref`.

Instead use

```
\refstepcounter{enclosure}
```

then the counter is incremented in the same way but its value becomes the current reference number so `\label` will pick it up and you can reference it with `\ref`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `\label` command at end document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcounter{enclosure}
\newcommand{\totalenclosures}{Total Enclosures:~\ref{tot@lencl@sures}}
\newcommand{\enclosure}{%
  \stepcounter{enclosure}%
  Enclosure~\theenclosure
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocounter{enclosure}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{enclosure}\label{tot@lencl@sures}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\totalenclosures\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\totalenclosures
\end{document}
```

The strange `\label{tot@lencl@sures}` is meant to be a string that you don't use in the document. The counter is stepped down and then "refstepped" up to have the correct value available for `\label`.

It's a bit more complicated if you want that `\totalenclosures` shows "No Enclosure" if there's none in the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{refcount} % for \getrefnumber
\newcounter{enclosure}
\newcommand{\totalenclosures}{%
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{tot@lencl@sures}=0
    No Enclosure%
  \else
    Total Enclosures:~\ref{tot@lencl@sures}%
  \fi
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocounter{enclosure}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{enclosure}\label{tot@lencl@sures}%
}
\newcommand{\enclosure}{%
  \stepcounter{enclosure}%
  Enclosure~\theenclosure
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\totalenclosures\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\enclosure\\
\totalenclosures
\end{document}
```